# Late closing of opinion-based post?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, opinion-based

Post closed as late as 2023Jan20

[What is it about Magnus Carlsen?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/929/what-is-it-about-magnus-carlsen)

Even Brian Towers ♦  edited Jul 20, 2019 at 11:33 (I assume mod at the time? Or not?)

But only 3.5 years later

> Post Closed as "Opinion-based" by SecretAgentMan, Brian Towers♦ occurred Jan 30 at 18:04

What's up with that? Did the standard for opinion-based change in the last 3.5 years?

Answer (score 8):

Since I've been called out, I'll answer for my part on my reasoning and let others educate me on my mistakes as they see fit. I was acting in good faith and have an open mind on the subject.

The OP asked multiple questions.
"*[W]what makes Carlsen so good?*"
"*Why are people so confident in Carlsen?*"
"*Does he have something other players such as Aronian don't have?*"
"*Where is all this coming from?*" (see [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/929/26335) for context for this)

The day I cast the vote, it was my first time viewing this question. When I read the question, the net effect of the four questions seemed to solicit exceptionally broad or opinionated answers (see [close reasons](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)).

The answers that exist are reasonable, yet one includes language like "*I imagine that his...*"

Further, *I imagine* the site was much newer in 2012. A cursory look at many SE sites shows different standards in the first few years. There's no judgement and it isn't meant to be critical of those who volunteered their time in 2012. My meager contributions certainly don't even compare.